# simplify a google sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am currently using the following formula

=SUMIFS(January!$J:$J,January!$G:$G,"y",January!$K:$K,"60")+SUMIFS(January!$J:$J,January!$G:$G,"n",January!$K:$K,"60")+SUMIFS(January!$J:$J,January!$G:$G,"e",January!$K:$K,"60")

I'm pulling numbers from another sheet in the same workbook and wanting to sum column J based on other criteria. However, the only reason I have it so long is because I want to sum if column G is y OR n OR e so that I can see the total $ amount sold in all 3 categories together that are also "60" in column K.

I may just not be understanding how to use them, but I have tried to use FILTER to get everything down. I just would prefer to have a shorter formula if possible.

I also tried using January@$G:$G,{"y","n","e"} and {"y|n|e"}. In the first case it only returned based on the y and in the second it returned a value of $0.00 when there should have been a number.

In other areas I have data that I'm trying to distill by even more criteria and they get REALLY long. Ultimately that's fine if it's getting that data, but the longer the formula the more that can be wrong and get me the incorrect data.

I would like to know if there is a shorter way to return the numbers I'm looking for.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with *realistic*-demo data and expected output(**manually entered**) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the [**anonymous blank sheet maker**](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) provided by [*docs community forum*](https://support.google.com/) incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

Answer (score 0):

Try this compact formula using the FILTER and SUM functions:

```excel
=SUM(FILTER(January!$J:$J, (January!$G:$G="y") + (January!$G:$G="n") + (January!$G:$G="e"), January!$K:$K="60"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make name range from A to K like "january".
Use query function.

```
=query(january,"select sum(J) where (G='e' or G='n' or G='y') and K=60",0)
```